# Ext.Calendar duplicate error

Tags: extjs, calendar, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

Tell me please, how i can create two Ext.calendar object?

write this code, and he say 
Ext.Error: Registering duplicate id "left-col" with this manager

```
    var lPanel = Ext.create('Ext.calendar.CalendarPanel', {
        id: 'app-calendar-left',
        region: 'west',
        width: '50%',
        minWidth: 300,
        eventStore: Ext.create('Ext.calendar.data.MemoryEventStore', {
            data: Ext.calendar.data.Events.getData()
        }),
        calendarStore: this.calendarStore,
        border: 1,
        activeItem: 3,
        monthViewCfg: {
            showHeader: true,
            showWeekLinks: true,
            showWeekNumbers: true
        }
    });

    var rPanel = Ext.create('Ext.calendar.CalendarPanel', {
        id: 'app-calendar-right',
        region: 'center',
        width: '50%',
        minWidth: 300,
        eventStore: Ext.create('Ext.calendar.data.MemoryEventStore', {
            data: Ext.calendar.data.Events.getData()
        }),
        calendarStore: this.calendarStore,
        border: 1,
        activeItem: 3,
        monthViewCfg: {
            showHeader: true,
            showWeekLinks: true,
            showWeekNumbers: true
        }
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'border',
        items: [lPanel, cPanel]
    });
```

Help somebody, i not know what doing with this error

Comment: Dom elements require unique ids. Try changing the id for one of your panels.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be caused by giving the 'width' attribute in a border layout in the 'center' region, try removing that.  Also, I don't believe minWidth makes sense on the 'center' region of a border layout, remove that too.  The 'west' region should have width defined in pixels in the border layout.

Comment: I have updated my answer, I think your problem may be related to how you have nested things in the border layout.